# Fix My Firebase database Chat Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello everyone im trying to make a simple chat app using google firebase db.

im facing the problem  please help me.

when i want to insert new element in child .
**But  it's inserting into root of database**

Like blow image.

[image]

But  I want  to insert Like .

[image]

Here is My Activity Code

```
public class RoomChat extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    String room_name,userName;
    EditText getMessage;
    TextView setMe;
    Button button;

    DatabaseReference root ;
    private String temp_key;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);

        button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        getMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        setMe=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        room_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Roomname");

        userName =getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");

        setTitle("Room -"+room_name);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()){
         case R.id.button:
             goIntoChatRoom();
             break;

     }
    }

    private void goIntoChatRoom() {

        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

        Log.i("RoomChat",root.getRef().child(room_name).toString());

        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        temp_key = root.push().getKey();

        Log.i("RoomChat","tempkey :"+temp_key);

        root.updateChildren(map);

        DatabaseReference message = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(temp_key);

        Log.i("RoomChat",message.toString());


        Map<String,Object> chatRoomMap2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        chatRoomMap2.put("name",userName);

        chatRoomMap2.put("message",getMessage.getText().toString());

        message.updateChildren(chatRoomMap2);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to change this piece of line :

```
root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);
```

to

```
root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(room_name);
```